# Running SDL code in SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, windows, xforwarding

I have a C program using SDL on my linux PC, when I try to launch this program from my windows pc with ssh it give me an error : `no protocol specified` and `no available device`. I have try to start SSH with `-X` or `export DISPLAY=0` but it doesn't work. What should I do ?

When I try with root : `error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environement`

Thanks

Comment: Try `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` is used to execute a remote shell, therefore it is usually for text-oriented commands (as opposed to graphical applications, like SDL ones). So don't expect graphical application to be able to run remotely through ssh.

Fortunately, `ssh` is a powerful tool: owing to the network-friendly X protocol, `ssh` provides a way to connect remote X applications to your local X server with the `-X` option (X11 forwarding).

What it does basically, is open a virtual display on the remote machine (let's say `:10`) by just listening on TCP port 6010 (port 6000+n corresponds to X11 display n) and forwarding everything to your local port, the one corresponding to your current X11 display (usually `:0`, listening on port 6000).

If you got me right, for everything to work, you not only need to use `ssh -X`, **you must use an X11 server locally**.

Windows does not come with an X11 server, so you must download and install one. Sorry, I'm blessed enough to not use Windows, and I have none to recommend. FWIW, on the Internet, some mention "Cygwin/X" (or xwin?), others "[VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)".

Once you have an X11 server running under Windows, what is important is that `ssh` uses that X11 server. Maybe the most straightforward is to run an X11 terminal from your local X server, and from that terminal execute `ssh -X`. Maybe just `export DISPLAY=:0` before executing `ssh -X` would be enough. TBH, I don't know and I won't be able to help you further.

Comment: Mmmh okey I see, I just turn off windows and boot from usb key with ubuntu. But I will try what you explain me with X11, thanks you !